# ruby on rails : about file upload and show file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently, we can save various files using database and S3. However, it is not possible to display those files well.

The code below is the showviewfile code. And there are two things I want to do here.

```
　　　　　<div class="listing_content">
            <% if @listing.file_content_type == 'video/mp4' then %>
              <%= video_tag @listing.file, :controls => true, width: "640", height: "360" %>
            <% elsif @listing.file_content_type == "image/jpg" || "image/jpeg" || "image/png" || "image/gif" then %>
              <%= image_tag @listing.file, :width => 640, :height => 340 %>
            <% elsif @listing.file_content_type == 'audio/mpeg' || 'audio/x-mpeg' || 'audio/mp3' || 'audio/x-mp3' || 'audio/mpeg3' || 'audio/x-mpeg3' || 'audio/mpg' || 'audio/x-mpg' || 'audio/x-mpegaudio' then %>
              <%= audio_tag @listing.file, :controls => true %>
            <% else %>
              <%= image_tag @listing.file %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
```

The first is to display the saved file for each format.
Second, see the image below. It means that audio files are not displayed properly.

[image]

So, I'd like to solve these problems, but I do not know how to solve it. How can we solve it?

model file

```
validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio', 'video/mp4', 'text/plain', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/pdf', "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
```

please tell me！！

Comment: can you confirm that the files are being uploaded properly? also what gem are you using for the file upload

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I don't know what file you're uploading, or how it's uploaded, or how it's processed, or what the value of `file_content_type` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least a problem in your conditions:
alpha || beta will just evaluate as beta if alpha is "true-ish".

Try changing your conditionals to something like

```
['audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 
 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3'].include?(@listing.file_content_type)
```

This is probably why it's giving you an image instead of playing an audio file appropriately. The way you have it, unless your file is mp4, gif, or mpegaudio, you will get an image.

Answer (score 0):

What library do you use for uploading ?

If it's carrierwave / paperclip maybe try to give @listing.file.url as a parameter instead ?